# how to create controls for a character in a game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am a beginner programmer. I do not understand how to create controls for a character in a game in swift.
The game will contain buttons: left, right, jump and action.
I tired through `touchesBegan`, but the left and right buttons do not work at constant pressure.

Comment: Consider using CoreMotion for your character's left and right movement and buttons for actions such as jump, fire, etc...

Comment: Need to create controls on the press, without accelerometer

Comment: Then your only other alternative is to do what Jad suggested and use the touches methods. An action starts at touchesBegan and stops at touchesEnded. There are no other options.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to implement `touchesEnded` as well.
The easy way to do this is to set a flag to true in touchesBegan and to false in `touchesEnded`. This way your loop will run as long as he flag is set to true (`touchesBegan`) and will stop when it is set to false (`touchesEnded`).
Hope this helps, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But maybe there is a better way to control the character?

Comment: I currently do not code in swift, but you can find a lot of examples online

Comment: var fingerIsOnLButton = false
var actionL = SKAction()
let distanceToMove = CGFloat(Character.position.x + 50.0)
let actionLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0, duration: 5)
actionL = SKAction.sequence([actionLeft])
//Left
        
        let LButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Left")
        LButton.name = LeftButton
        LButton.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: LButton.frame.size)
        LButton.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        LButton.position = CGPointMake(300, 600)
        LButton.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
        addChild(LButton)

Comment: override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let body:SKPhysicsBody? = self.physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation)
        
       
     
        
        if body?.node?.name == LeftButton {

            
            Character.runAction(actionL)
        
            fingerIsOnLButton = true
  
        }
    }
    
    
    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
       
            fingerIsOnLButton = false
       
}
    
}

Comment: can you edit your question and post your code there so i can see it clearly ??